# all dfs replication groups failing at the same time

Tags: windows, replication, dfs, dfs-r

We have 2 pairs of fileshare servers. All servers are virtual Windows 2008 R2. Each pair is replicating over a WAN. Occasionally all DFS replication groups fail at the same time.

I could not find any relevant logs on the DFS servers. The following Event IDs appear on the fileshare servers:

4010 - The DFS Replication service detected that the replicated folder at local path PATH has been removed from the configuration.

3006 - The DFS Replication service has detected that the replication group GROUP was removed from the configuration.

This has happened 4 times over the last year. We have been unable to correlate the incidents to any particular environment change, time of day, or incident in the environment using shared hardware such as ESXi hosts, storage, or network.

The first 3 times the replication groups were completely wiped out of DFS Management and Active Directory. After the third time we decided to prevent accidental deletion of the AD object. This 4th time the AD object and replication groups remain, however DFS Management reports "The topology is not fully connected" and lists the Local Path as  for each target.

Comment: Does the DFS-R occurs on just one domain or more? When you are experiencing the said issue, does replication between Domain Controllers continues as per normal? Also, is there a chance the replication group to contain any server/servers that may be losing network connectivity for any reason?

Comment: We only have DFS-R installed and configured in one domain. I'm unsure about the replication between Domain controllers, but it is a pretty large environment, a few thousand Windows servers. If domain controllers stopped communicating with each other I think we would have many other problems. I'll follow up with Telecom next week, to see if I can get some data however we lose network connectivity during patching and it doesn't blow up replication. Thanks!